# What is the correct file name for the interface "IRepository<T>"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, naming-conventions

Just curious what people would name the file that contains the generic interface `IRepository<T>`.

IRepositoryT.cs?

**Update**

One minor point to add. Normally, when you change the name of a class file, Visual Studio asks if you want to do a rename on the class as well. In the case of `IRepository<T>`, no matter what I name the file (IRepository or IRepositoryT or IRepositoryOfT, etc.), the link between the file name and the class name is never established.

Comment: "IRepository.cs" should be good enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convention for Filenames of Generic Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804036/convention-for-filenames-of-generic-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would name it as I say it: IRepositoryOfT.cs

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would use `IRepository.cs`. The only difference is when I, for a generic class, also has a nongeneric version of the same, either for compatibility with legacy code, or to provide static methods available to any T.

In this case I would name them:

- IRepository.NonGeneric.cs
- IRepository.cs

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use *IRepository.cs*. And unless they are very big classes, I tend to keep `IRepository` and `IRepository<T>` in the same file. Usually with the non-generic on top, since the generic one usually extends the non-generic one.

When I have split it into two files, I have usually used *IRepository(Of T).cs*, but the suggestion from others here with *IRepositoryOfT.cs* sure is a good one. Might use that one :p

Answer (score 1):

I would go with IRepository.cs

I don't think the fact that the type is generic should make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804036/convention-for-filenames-of-generic-classes) is helpful.

Comment: Oo, I like that...`IRepositoryOfT`

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you have IRepository also, and you like to keep different interface definitions in different files.

If so, `IRepositoryT.cs`, or else `IRepository.cs`

And I'd put it in a folder named Interfaces, but that's me, and I'm a bit OCD in this area

Comment: I would say "IRepository.cs" and "IRepositoryGeneric.cs" instead. Maybe even include both in the same file and name it "IRepository.cs"

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with the same file idea, depending on the size of the interface. Also IRepositoryGeneric.cs is a much better idea! Thanks!