# How to name generic class\interface filename?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, generics, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to name C# source files for generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108189/how-to-name-c-sharp-source-files-for-generic-classes)

Today I noticed that while watching built-in generic class\interface metadata in VS2010 the window name contains the exact (well, missing `out` keyword) name of the class/interface, i.e.:

[image]

Then I tried to name my own cs file, containing a generic class, accordingly, say `Foo<T>.cs` and got an error, saying that `<` and `>` are not acceptable.

So,  intuitively I can see that, while displaying built-in class/interface metadata the name of the window can be substituted by the IDE. It's OK. But is there any naming convention (some best practise) for the names of the files, containg generics, within a project. That is, if I had both `Foo<T>` and `Foo`, am I expected to keep them in separate files and how should I name these file then?

Comment: Show us the code you wrote that gave you the error.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What code? The error occured in the new file wizard

Comment: That name is not filename, but class name, because you get the code from metadata. And I don't believe there is naming convention for files containing generic classes.

Comment: Oh, I see.  `<` and `>` are illegal in a file name.  See the duplicate question I linked.