# StyleCop SA1402 and Generics

Tags: c#, generics, stylecop

I think **SA1402** is a great rule but I have problem with generics. I've got a class that uses the `Func` delegate, so the names roughly parallel that signature. That is, I have classes named `Operation<TType>`, `Operation<T, TType>`, `Operation<T1, T2, TType>` and so on. According to **SA1402**, I need to put all these small classes in separate files and come up with some strange decoration for the file name.  Additionally, if I need to change one of these items I'll typically need to make changes to the rest. This seems less supportable than a single module.

Does it make sense for **SA1402** to allow generics of the same basic class (as well as partials) to reside in one file? In this case all permutations of the class `Operation` would reside in 'Operation.cs'.

Comment: Several suggestions here: [Convention for Filenames of Generic Classes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804036/convention-for-filenames-of-generic-classes

Answer (score 4):

They are several nameing convension. It seems the most popular is

> Operation[TType].cs
>
> Operation[T,TType].cs
>
> Operation[T1, T2, TType].cs

But you can also use something more classic, like

> Operation`1.cs
>
> Operation`2.cs
>
> Operation`3.cs

(see [Convention for Filenames of Generic Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804036/convention-for-filenames-of-generic-classes))

Answer (score 4):

I tend to agree with you, *in general, SA1402 is a good idea*.  But in this specific case, and others like it ([i have a generic and non-generic implementation of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063061/516433)).  Like many others I think  [***having more than one class per file is totally fine if it makes sense***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435040/516433).  I choose to ignore this warning at a very specific `Scope` and `Target` level:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage(
    "StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules",
    "SA1402:FileMayOnlyContainASingleType",
    Justification = "How else would we name generic and non generic (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063061/516433).",
    Scope = "type",
    Target = "~T:Pastdev.Cli.AppResources`1<!!0>")]
```

Comment: You have specified the Target on a generic class with one type param - do you have any reference on how to notate generic classes with more than one type param?

Comment: I have no reference, but when using Visual Studio to generate it, it appears: `[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1600:Elements should be documented", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "type", Target = "~T:Mitre.CliApp.IO.CircularBuffer\`2")]`.  Also, probably worth noting that I don't think you can have multiple targets on the same line.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `Operation<TType>.cs` approach will work if you have overridden the StyleCop's `fileNamingConvention` setting ([File naming conventions](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md#file-naming-conventions)).

Otherwise, it works automatically if you name your file like: `Operation{TType}.cs`, etc. (Note the curly braces)

Comment: Yes, I know how to override Stylecop settings. The whole idea is to change your code so that you pass without changing the settings.