# Move Foo and Foo<T> with ReSharper to matching files

Tags: c#, resharper-8.0

**Code**

I would like to use the ReSharper *Move Types Into Matching Files* functionality to move the code below which is written in a single `.cs`'. file:

```
public abstract class Foo
{

}

public abstract class Foo<T> : Foo
{

}
```

Executing the ReSharper refactoring causes this exception:

> Can not move class Foo because there is another declaration that
>   will be moved into file 'Foo.cs'.

**Question**

I can think of two outcomes of which either are ok by me:

1. Move both `Foo` and `Too<T>` into `Foo.cs`
2. Move `Foo` into `Foo.cs` and move `Foo<T>` into `FooOfT.cs`

So, the question remains:

1. Is there another best naming practise that does not conflict with resharper?, or
2. Is there a way to configure ReSharper to support this naming?

**Note**

- Because Generics are unique for each possible combination of constraints,  the `Foo` class is my interface class.  Therefore I won't rename `Foo<T>` to `Bar<T>`.
- I do not wish to rename `Foo` to `FooBase` as it is already an abstract class which makes the explicit 'Base' suffix redundant.
- I cannot refactor `Foo` to `IFoo` as `Foo` is my conceptual interface (because of a required basic implementation.

Comment: I've sometimes named generic files Foo`1.cs to denote one generic type argument on Foo. But this isn't using ReSharper.

Comment: "At Microsoft, they use `ClassNameOfT.cs`." http://stackoverflow.com/a/804114/781792

Comment: @TimS. That is exactly my second suggestion. However, It seems that unfortunately ReSharper does not support this naming convention.

Comment: @MauriceStam That'll work until you have something like your own `Tuple` with multiple type arguments, but in different files lol

Comment: Create a folder for one or the other or two folders, one for each. Then they can have the same file name.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that is no solution because I would like the folder structure to follow the namespace structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to tell Resharper to append the generic parameters of the filename. It will just use the class name, i.e. `Foo`, `Foo<T>` and `Foo<A, B, C>` all have `Foo.cs` as the filename, but - and that's the problem - ReSharper doesn't seem to know that this possibility exists and will show you an error in this scenario. Really nothing you can do about it except [logging a bug or feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider these options:

- Use `AbstractFoo`
- Change Foo to an interface, if possible, and use `IFoo`
- Use `GenericFoo`
- Use different namespaces for `Foo` and `Foo<T>` and put them in different folders.

Comment: Unfortunately `Foo` is already my 'conceptual' interface class. However I require some basic implementation therefore I use an abstract class instead of an c# interface.

Comment: You could also develop a Resharper plugin that does what you want.