# Faster way of obtaining a property from an element contained in a dictionary of dynamics?

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic, data-structures

Right now I have this interface called `IMessageConfiguration<T>` that implements a property called `Label` (of type `byte`). I have a map of labels to their relative message configurations in the following structure:

`Dictionary<byte, dynamic> configurationMap = new Dictionary<byte, dynamic>();`

Now, although the dictionary is dynamic I am only filling it with either `IMessageConfiguration<double>` or `IMessageConfiguration<uint>`. Regardless of which type is at each dictionary entry, the entry will have the property `Label` because all entries will ultimately have the `IMessageConfiguration<T>` base type. *I do however understand that the compiler will have no knowledge of this.*

I am writing a routine to go through the dictionary and obtain the `Label` property for each of the `IMessageConfiguration<T>` entries. Here is my current attempt at doing this:

```
public IList<byte> GetLabels()
{
    IList<byte> labels = new List<byte>();

    // obtain all of the labels
    foreach (var configuration in this.configurationMap)
    {
        if (configuration.Value is IMessageConfiguration<double>)
        {
            labels.Add((configuration.Value as IMessageConfiguration<double>).Label);
        }
        else if (configuration.Value is IMessageConfiguration<uint>)
        {
            labels.Add((configuration.Value as IMessageConfiguration<uint>).Label);
        }
    }

    return labels;
}
```

Is there a way to more cleanly obtain all of the `Label` properties for each of the message configurations?

As asked in the comments, here is the full definition for the `IMessageConfiguration<T>` interface.

```
public interface IMessageConfiguration<T>
{
    string Description { get; }
    byte Label { get; }
    ushort LSB { get; }
    ushort MSB { get; }
    double Resolution { get; }
    int SignBit { get; }
    string Title { get; }
    string Units { get; }
    uint Encode(T data);
    T Decode(uint message);
}
```

Comment: Providing full definition of `IMessageConfiguration<T>` interface might help to answer.

Comment: @Evk I guess I could do that, but it's really just a container-type class that has a bunch of dummy data properties.

Comment: My point is - if `Label` property is not related to type `T` (for example if `Label` is always `string`) - you can move it to parent interface `IMessageConfiguration` and then have `Dictionary<byte, IMessageConfiguration` with easy access to that Label (or even if it's still dynamic - access to Label is still easier).

Comment: @Evk Yes, good point. Let me provide that interface definition, and yes label is always byte.

Comment: @Evk Updated to include the interface definition for `IMessageConfiguration<T>`.

Comment: But I don't see type `T` is used anywhere there. Is it intended?

Comment: @Evk I left out two methods on-purpose, one second. Let me add them back.

Comment: Move the generic declaration towards `T Decode<T>(uint message)` and `uint Encode<T>(T data)` or create 2 interfaces, where one would be the non generic `IMessageConfiguration` and the second one would be `IMessageConfiguration<T> : IMessageConfiguration`  that just implements the generic methods

Comment: @Icepickle That seems like a good idea.

Comment: @Icepickle How would you name the C# (.cs) for adding the interfaces like that to my project?

Comment: I would actually keep them in the same file :)

Comment: @Icepickle Okay. I also asked the same question to Evk down below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you should avoid `dynamic` whenever possible. In your case you can put all non-`T` related properties to parent interface:

```
public interface IMessageConfiguration
{
    string Description { get; }
    byte Label { get; }
    ushort LSB { get; }
    ushort MSB { get; }
    double Resolution { get; }
    int SignBit { get; }
    string Title { get; }
    string Units { get; }
}

public interface IMessageConfiguration<T> : IMessageConfiguration {
    uint Encode(T data);
    T Decode(uint message);
}
```

And use `Dictionary<byte, IMessageConfiguration>` instead. Even if you insist on using `dynamic` for some reason - you can do `yourDict.OfType<IMessageConfiguration>().Select(c => c.Label).ToList()` to get those labels.

Comment: Would you put both of those interface types into the same (.cs) file in your project?

Comment: @Evk I wouldn't see why, they are closely related, and there is no naming difference of the interfaces, for me, in this form, they belong together

Comment: @Snoopy well I think so too, I just mean some people would argue with that and it's not widely accepted.

Comment: @Evk What would some people propose as an alternate, though?

Comment: @Snoopy you can see some options (including what is claimed used by Microsoft itself) in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/804036/5311735

Comment: @Evk Okay, thanks for that... but I'll probably stick with doing it the way that both you and IcePickle are doing it, which seems more concise.